# Automatically loading 2 packages when one depends on the other

Tags: r, package

I have two R packages, `foo` and `bar`. `bar` depends on `foo` and as such in its description file it has the line `Depends: foo`. I would like to automatically load these two packages whenever I begin R. As such, I wrote the following in `.Rprofile`:

```
options(defaultPackages = c([various other packages], "foo", "bar")
```

where `[various other packages]` is just a placeholder for the various other packages I automatically load such as `stats`.

When I start R, this works fine. However, the following: error occurs when I try to re-install `foo`

```
Error: package ‘foo’ is required by ‘bar’ so will not be detached
```

This halts the installation process and `foo` is not successfully re-installed with any changes. I can re-install `bar` without issue.

What causes this error and is there any way to get around it while still automatically loading the two packages.

Comment: Have you tried just putting
`library(foo)` and 
`library(bar)`
in your `.Rprofile`? Does the same issue occur then?

Comment: This throws the same error.

Comment: If you do `library(bar)` from the console, do both libraries install correctly?  If so, it's a loading-order problem.  You may need to explicitly load one of the standard packages in an `.Rprofile` line, e.g.  `library(utils)` before loading your foobar packages. (i'm not saying that `utils` is the required package, just that *something* is).

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused due to R still having the package loaded in the environment, I did the following example with the `Agreement` package which lists `R2HTML` in depends:

```
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"     
> install.packages("Agreement", lib = .libPaths()[2], repos = "http://dirichlet.mat.puc.cl/", quiet = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
package ‘Agreement’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> library("Agreement")
Loading required package: R2HTML
Warning messages:
1: package ‘Agreement’ was built under R version 3.1.2 
2: package ‘R2HTML’ was built under R version 3.1.2 
> search()
 [1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:Agreement" "package:R2HTML"   
 [4] "package:stats"     "package:graphics"  "package:grDevices"
 [7] "package:utils"     "package:datasets"  "package:methods"  
[10] "Autoloads"         "package:base"     
> install.packages("Agreement", lib = .libPaths()[2], repos = "http://dirichlet.mat.puc.cl/", quiet = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
Warning: package ‘Agreement’ is in use and will not be installed
> install.packages("R2HTML", lib = .libPaths()[2], repos = "http://dirichlet.mat.puc.cl/", quiet = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
Warning: package ‘R2HTML’ is in use and will not be installed
```

Replicated your error, which is occurring because the packages are still attached. A simple workaround would to manually unload with this one-liner before installing again:

```
> for(k in c("Agreement", "R2HTML")) while(paste0("package:", k) %in% search()) detach(paste0("package:", k), unload = TRUE, character.only = TRUE)
> search()
[1] ".GlobalEnv"        "package:stats"     "package:graphics" 
[4] "package:grDevices" "package:utils"     "package:datasets" 
[7] "package:methods"   "Autoloads"         "package:base"     
> install.packages("Agreement", lib = .libPaths()[2], repos = "http://dirichlet.mat.puc.cl/", quiet = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
package ‘Agreement’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

This install includes `R2HTML` but if you want to be sure, then you will be able to run the following as well:

```
> install.packages("R2HTML", lib = .libPaths()[2], repos = "http://dirichlet.mat.puc.cl/", quiet = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)
package ‘R2HTML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```